# Grunt Exiting When It Should Be Watching

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am developing a node app that interacts with IRC.

My `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {     
  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      js: {
        files: [
          'index.js',
          'brains.js',
          'lib/*.js'
        ],
        tasks: ['develop'],
        options: { nospawn: true }
      }
    },
    develop: {
      server: {
        file: 'index.js'
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-develop');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['develop']);

};
```

When I execute grunt it states that it completed and exits. How can I keep grunt watching like in a web based node app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling `grunt`, the default task is running: `grunt.registerTask('default', ['develop']);`. Run `grunt watch` instead, or change `['develop']` to `['watch']`.

Comment: I'd say change it to `grunt.registerTask('default', ['develop', 'watch']);` makes more sense since it seems he wants to do both.