# Using grunt-develop

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I created a simple NodeJS + Express app that runs when I use `node app.js`.  Now, I'm trying to integrate [grunt-develop](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/grunt-develop).  I configured it like so:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    develop: {
        server: {
            file: 'app.js'
        }
    }
});
```

When I run `grunt develop`, the log is:

```
Running "develop:server" (develop) task

[grunt-develop] > started application "app.js".
Done, without errors.
```

The server doesn't start and I get prompted for the next command. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the comment on [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813462/grunt-exiting-when-it-should-be-watching):

"Change it to `grunt.registerTask('default', ['develop', 'watch'])`"